# pytest unable to find test files files in python

Tags: python, pytest

I just started using pytest, according to the pytest.org entering $ pytest should find all the '_test*' files, but when I am running the pytest command it is not finding any file by itself.

```
Raghavs-MacBook-Pro:~ raghav$ pwd
/Users/raghav

Raghavs-MacBook-Pro:~ raghav$ ls
test_dict.py test_sample.py test_str.py

Raghavs-MacBook-Pro:~ raghav$ pytest

platform darwin -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.4.2, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /Users/raghav, inifile:
```

even this is not working

```
Raghavs-MacBook-Pro:~ raghav$ pytest 

platform darwin -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.4.2, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /Users/raghav, inifile:
test_sample.py F
```

But it is working like this.

```
Raghavs-MacBook-Pro:~ raghav$ pytest test_sample.py

platform darwin -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.4.2, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /Users/raghav, inifile:
collected 1 item
```

Comment: Looks like it's working if you get the tests executed: `test_sample.py F`.

Comment: @hoefling so when I am typing pytest, it is not making any computation like collected 1 item or anything and even after typing the name of test file like what I did 'test_sample.py F', It is still not giving any result. But when I am entering them all together like '$ pytest test_sample.py', only then it is working. 
But the way they mentioned here 'https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/' it should work even with  $ pytest. isn't it?

Comment: It should work unless you did misconfigure it. Do you have config files `pytest.ini`, `tox.ini` or a `setup.cfg` in your test root dir?

Comment: try with verbose options `-vv` to force the output.